# Removing First Item from listbox while binding to listbox

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have parsed the feed  http://www.toucheradio.com/toneradio/android/toriLite/AndroidRSS.xml
And all items from rss feed displayed in listbox.Now I dont want to get first item I have to omit it.How Can I do it.

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
namespace tori
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        // is there network connection available
       if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No network connection available!");
            return;
        }
        // start loading XML-data
        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(" http://www.toucheradio.com/toneradio/android/toriLite/AndroidRSS.xml", UriKind.Absolute);
        downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(ChannelDownloaded);
        downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
    }

    void ChannelDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the XML-file!");
        }
        else
        {
            // Deserialize if download succeeds

            XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

            var queue = from item in document.Descendants("item")
                        select new Item
                        {
                            title = item.Element("title").Value
                            ,
                            link = item.Element("link").Value
                            ,
                            ThumbnailUrl = item.Element(item.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("media") + "thumbnail").Attribute("url").Value
                            ,

                        };

           itemsList.ItemsSource = queue;
}
}

 public class Item
       {
             public string title { get; set; }
            public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
            public string link { get; set; }
       }
```

If I write queue.RemoveAt(0);
i was getting error at RemoveAt.
Can anybody please tell me how can I do that.
Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using LINQ `Skip` extension method (documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx)).
Just try the sample below:

```
itemsList.ItemsSource = queue.Skip(1);
```

As well you can rewrite the query to omit the first item before applying the projection in the select method using the methods chain approach:

```
var queue = document.Descendants("item")
            .Skip(1)
            .Select(item => new Item
                    {
                        title = item.Element("title").Value,
                        link = item.Element("link").Value,
                        ThumbnailUrl = item.Element(item.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("media") + "thumbnail").Attribute("url").Value,
                    })
            .ToList();

itemsList.ItemsSource = queue;
```

**UPDATE / DUE TO COMMENTS**

And as well if you need to skip items at certain indexes you may use the `Where` method and the `HasSet` as in the sample below:

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
var indexes = new HashSet<int> { 1, 3, 4 }; 

var queue = document.Descendants("item")
    .Select(item => new Item
    {
        title = item.Element("title").Value,
        link = item.Element("link").Value,
        ThumbnailUrl =
            item.Element(item.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("media") + "thumbnail").Attribute("url").Value,
    })
    .Where((x, i) => !indexes.Contains(i))
    .ToList();

Items.ItemsSource = queue;
```

Comment: Thanku soo much.If we need to display only first item and omit remaining items.Can we skip multiple items.ManyThanks

Comment: What can I do if I need to skip two or three items at random positions

Comment: @deepu If there is any kind of criteria you are using to detect those ?

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand.I mean If I need to display  selected items can I use Count,Skip.ElementAt
(2) like this.                                       XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Channel));
        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
        Channel channel = (Channel)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());
   // remove the first item
        if (channel.Collection.Count > 0)
            channel.Collection.RemoveAt(0);

        this.myListBox.ItemsSource = channel.Collection;  ManyThanks

Comment: @deepu now, I'm not quite sure, if I've undestood you ) I suppose you need to skip the elements at certain indexes, right ?
If so, I would suggest using the `Where` method. E.g. Assuming you need to skip items with index 1,3 and 4 the following code will work: `var indexes = new HashSet<int> {1, 3, 4}; this.myListBox.ItemsSource.Collection = channel.Collection.Where((x, i) => !indexes.Contains(i))` assuming that the `channel.Collection` property implements `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: The code in the prev comment will basically show all the items with indexes different than 1,3 and 4. As well no need to check for the `Count` property as you are not accessing the items by index.

Comment: @deepu please accept the answer if it answered your question

Comment: But In case of queue I was not getting.In collection I have done earler only.But in queue not displaying required items.It was not working with Skip.Thankyou.I was also getting error at HashSet.

Comment: @deepu did you add the `using System.Collections.Generic;` for the `HashSet` ?

Comment: @deepu I think I've got your problem. If you're using the `LongListSelector` you will have to add the `ToList` method in the end of the methods chain. Please check the answer.

Comment: NONO I have not used longlistselector.And I have added using System.Collection.Generic namespace.Eventhough I was getting error.